# Constructing member objects without default constructor conditionally

Tags: c++, constructor

I want to construct class members without default constructor conditionally.
Basically I want to do the following in the class constructor:

```
class X{
public:
    X(Config config) {
        if (config.getBool) memberA("yes");
        else memberA("no");
    }
}
```

The problem is that, as said before there is no default constructor for the class of `memberA` and therefore the compiler is unable to construct it resulting in an error.
Obviously I could do this:

```
class X{
public:
    X(Config config) : memberA("yes") {
    if (!config.getBool) memberA = MemberAClass("no");
    }
}
```

but I was wondering if there were a way to construct the member using an if clause but without calling the constructor twice in order to prevent side effects in static members of the class.

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that I actually needed two parameters, but the principle worked anyway:

```
X::X(Config cfg):member(cfg.getBool()?"yes":"no",cfg.getBool()?1:2){};
```

Comment: `class X::X(config) : memberA(config.getBool ? "yes" : "no") {}` ?

Comment: @Casey That should be an answer.

Comment: Yeah, that basically does the trick, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the constructor initialization list and conditional operator (instead of `if`) as follow:

```
X::X(const Config& config) : memberA(config.getBool() ? "yes" : "no")
{}
```

or create a function to compute the correct argument:

```
const char* compute_memberA_arg(const Config& config) {
    if (config.getBool()) { return "yes"; }
    else { return "no"; }
}

X::X(const Config& config) : memberA(compute_memberA_arg(config))
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the update, I'd suggest a (static) helper method:

```
MemberType X::initMemberA(bool flag) {
  return flag ? MemberType("yes", 1) : MemberType("no", 2);
}
X::X(Config cfg) : memberA(initMemberA(cfg.getBool())) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the major pitfalls of C++, that you cannot embed the construction of members into the constructor code. This is especially nasty when you need to use different constructors depending on the arguments. In these cases, the best workaround is to move (parts of) the initialization of your members into `init()` functions. Then you can do something like this:

```
class Foo {
    Bar bar;
public:
    Foo(bool flag) {
        if(flag) {
            bar.init("init from string");
        } else {
            bar.init(3, 7, 5);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Rather, it's one of the major pitfalls of the C++ community that so many programmers don't know how to do it. Don't use `init` functions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree: If you can't handle an `init()` function, you shouldn't use it. But then you have to concede defeat whenever a situation arises that requires an `init()` function. And these situations exist. Better make sure, you *can* handle them.

Comment: @cmaster: I've never seen such a situation, and this again is a case in which `init` functions are misplaced. As Jarod and Casey have shown, there are in fact multiple better alternatives.

Comment: @MSalters It is true, none of the examples here strictly requires the use of `init()` functions, not even the example I gave, even though using an `init()` function in that case is probably the best idea. But I have seen a case that does *require* an `init()` function. It's a little too complicate to explain in a comment, but it had to do with dynamically creating instances of unknown classes which need to know each other according to some description. Something along the lines of loading a .nib file on MacOS X, but with some different quirks.